# Google Signin ErrorCode: 16

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I'm implementing Google Signin into my android app. I thought I was ready but now I got an error like this: Status{statusCode=CANCELED, resolution=null} ErrorCode: 16

It happens in this method:

```
private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("WARN","signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

at line:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
```

I've searched for more than an hour in the internet for any solution's, but nothing works for me.

May someone know what to do?

Thanks alot!